# Android- Matrix can not be modified

Tags: android, matrix

I'm trying to set a background for my SurfaceView, but can't get it to fill the entire screen. The right and bottom are left black around my drawable, so I would like to scale it just a tad bit to fit each screen. A solution I found was to use a matrix to scale my bitmap. 
I set up what I would believe to be correct, based on a few examples, but it just crashes before opening, with errors about matrix can not be modified. Can't seem to figure out what I could be doing wrong.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MySurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {


SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
Thread ourThread = null;
boolean isRunning = true;

Bitmap Background;
Bitmap clouda;

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();


public MySurface(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);

}

public MySurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public MySurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    // do stuff that was in your original constructor...
    ourHolder = getHolder();
    ourThread = new Thread(this);
    ourThread.start();

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)     context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;

    Background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.island);
    clouda = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.clouda);


    Matrix matrix = getMatrix();

    RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, Background.getWidth(), Background.getHeight());
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    Log.d("tag", drawableRect.toString());
    Log.d("tag", viewRect.toString());

    matrix.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);





}


@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(isRunning){
        if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;


        Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas(); 


        canvas.drawBitmap(Background, matrix, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(clouda, 0, 0, null);

        ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

       }

   }



}
```

And here is my logcat, which I have two tags so that I can see the height and width of what I'm drawing:

```
07-26 00:25:23.649: D/dalvikvm(3966): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 59K, 7% free 2562K/2736K, paused 2ms, total 3ms
07-26 00:25:23.681: D/dalvikvm(3966): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 2900K/3076K, paused 3ms, total 4ms
07-26 00:25:23.693: I/dalvikvm-heap(3966): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.285MB for 2457612-byte allocation
07-26 00:25:23.697: D/dalvikvm(3966): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 5300K/5480K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
07-26 00:25:23.709: D/dalvikvm(3966): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 5300K/5480K, paused 7ms+0ms, total 9ms
07-26 00:25:23.745: D/tag(3966): RectF(0.0, 0.0, 640.0, 960.0)
07-26 00:25:23.749: D/tag(3966): RectF(0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 1184.0)
07-26 00:25:23.749: D/AndroidRuntime(3966): Shutting down VM
07-26 00:25:23.749: W/dalvikvm(3966): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa61b9908)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hour24.by8by8/com.hour24.by8by8.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Matrix can not be modified
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:  Matrix can not be modified
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at android.graphics.Matrix$1.oops(Matrix.java:43)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at android.graphics.Matrix$1.setRectToRect(Matrix.java:205)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at com.hour24.by8by8.MySurface.init(MySurface.java:69)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at com.hour24.by8by8.MySurface.<init>(MySurface.java:31)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at com.hour24.by8by8.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-26 00:25:23.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3966):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is the line 69 at MySurface.java? The Exception is there

Comment: Have you considered using `Canvas#drawBitmap(Bitmap, Rect, Rect, Paint)` instead?

Comment: @joao2fast4u That would be the matrix.setRectToRect on 69, and I'm not sure what you mean for the getMatrix(), as that's all I have in my code

Comment: `getMatrix()` is a method in `SurfaceView`, and, obviously, the `Matrix` returned by this cannot be changed. Consider using the `drawBitmap()` overload noted in my last comment. It is very simple to implement. Change `drawableRect`'s type to `Rect`, and pass null for the `Paint` parameter. There's also a `drawBitmap(Bitmap, Rect, RectF, Paint)` overload, so `viewRect` is ok as it is.

Comment: @MikeM. Man..I have spent HOURS trying to make sense of Matrices, scaling Bitmaps, and just anything that could possibly be connected... and all it took was adding two rectangles. Thank you so much Mike for your help. You're a huge asset to the programming community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the `Canvas#drawBitmap(Bitmap, Rect, RectF, Paint)` method instead. Your code is most of the way there already. Change `drawableRect`'s type to `Rect`, make it and `viewRect` class members, and pass `null` for the `Paint` parameter.

Side note: In keeping with Java naming conventions, `Background` should be `background`.